# How do I get metricbeat to report normalized CPU percentages to Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, metricbeat

I have the following metricbeat simple configuration:

```
#==========================  Modules configuration ============================
metricbeat.modules:

#------------------------------- System Module -------------------------------
- module: system
  metricsets: ["cpu"]
  period: 10s
  cpu.metrics:  ["percentages", "normalized_percentages"]

#----------------------------- Logstash output --------------------------------
output.logstash:
# The Logstash hosts
    hosts: ["<ip>:5000"]
```

With this information, when I get to Kibana (or Grafana) and try to analyze the data, I only see the normal CPU fields, not the normalized ones, e.g.,

```
(...) 
"system": {
      "cpu": {
        "softirq": {
          "pct": 0
        },
        "user": {
          "pct": 0.0243
        },
        "nice": {
          "pct": 0
        },
        "irq": {
          "pct": 0
        },
        "iowait": {
          "pct": 0.0101
        },
        "idle": {
          "pct": 1.9545
        },
        "steal": {
          "pct": 0
        },
        "system": {
          "pct": 0.0111
        },
        "cores": 2
      }
    },
(...)
```

I do not see the normalized % as an option in either the "Add a filter" section in Kibana, or in the Index Patterns section, so it must not be getting in other way.

I'm running metricbeat 5.6.12 against a 6.4.2 ELK single-node cluster (inside Docker).

My logstash configuration looks like this:

```
input {
        beats {
                port => 5000
        }
}

## Add your filters / logstash plugins configuration here

output {
        elasticsearch {
                hosts => "elasticsearch:9200"
                manage_template => false
                index => "%{[@metadata][beat]}-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
                document_type => "%{[@metadata][type]}"
        }
}
```

I have already restarted metricbeat to load the configurations, and confirmed the problem is still happening.

Comment: Try removing the quotes and setting the line to `cpu.metrics:  [percentages, normalized_percentages]`, my guess is that metric beat is failing to parse your config and just falling back to the default percentages

Comment: Strip the quotes from `cpu` while youre trying

Comment: Although, thats not a common gotcha, so I may be incorrect about quotes messing something up. You could test your config for issues https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/libbeat/6.4/config-file-format-tips.html

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't seem to be that. Without the quotes, the problem still happens.

When using configtest:
```sudo metricbeat.sh -configtest```
then I get
```Config OK```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> metricbeat 5.6.12 against a 6.4.2 ELK

When rereading this today something clicked! It was just a version mismatch. Upon ensuring I was running a 6.x version of metricbeat, the metrics are now propagating correctly.